# Sessions hanging in killed/rollback preemptive_oledbops

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I have two sessions hanging in killed/rollback state. These are cancelled selects to PostgreSQL by `openquery`. What can I do with this? KILL UOW does nothing because I have transaction GUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'.

[image: sessions]

More disturbingly, the server looks like it's constantly consuming RAM and won't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill them on Postgre side if they're still running. Also, not sure what UOW means. As last resort, i think you have to restart the server :/